# captcha broken on Stack Overflow - No Challenge Shown

Tags: support, captcha

I attempted to post an answer this morning and got the *"Are You Human"* Captcha dialog -- however, it was just the captcha dialog window without any challenge captcha and no place to enter any response. The only action the window allowed was clicking `[X]`:

[image: captcha dialog]

Is captcha down? I posted answers 6 hours ago, same computer, same browser (firefox). I loaded a new instance of FF just to check. Same behavior, no challenge and no place to enter any response.

This is all I get:

[image]

There is no CAPTCHA box and all clicking on CAPTCHA does is send me to the Wikipedia captcha page.

Comment: I got this, checked the box, nothing happened. But the second time, it showed me a code, I typed in the code it asked me, got the green checkmark, but under it the text "Oops! Those aren't the correct words". Fail.

Comment: You see the white box with the Gray border above, you are meant to click it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The new Google Captcha can determine that you are human by *how you click the checkbox alone*; Meta Stack Overflow was [switched over yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244638/please-use-the-new-recaptcha-on-the-human-verification-dialog).

If the system cannot determine you are a human with enough confidence you'll be presented with a ReCaptcha text box anyway. If you are on a mobile device (where there is no mouse to track), you'll be presented with an easy image puzzle; you are asked to tap all images that represent the same thing as a sample image; like picking out all the cats among a matrix of pictures.

So, no, this is not a bug. Welcome to the new and improved are-you-a-human test!

Also see the Google Blog: [*Are you a robot? Introducing “No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA”*](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html)

If you are not seeing even the *I'm not a robot* checkbox, you are most likely using an extension that blocks required content or otherwise breaks the widget. Try loading the page in Private Browsing mode with all extensions disabled. You can force the captcha by loading your question here on Meta with `?captcha=1` appended to the URL, then editing a post. When submitting the test will be shown, even if you did not make any changes. The widget appears to rely on `apis.google.com`, `www.gstatic.com` and `fonts.gstatic.com` being available, for example.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the OP is stating. Even with the new reCAPTCHA he should see something more than a dialog window with just a close button, it is probably related though

Comment: @Joe: no, the checkbox **is it**. You clicking it is the test. There may be follow-up tests if the system isn't confident, but for most people, all you need to do is tick the big checkbox.

Comment: I know the checkbox is the captcha, the way the question is worded, I thought he meant pressing the close button was all he saw.

Comment: @Joe: the captcha change was implemented [21 hours ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244638/please-use-the-new-recaptcha-on-the-human-verification-dialog). I'm pretty damn confident the OP is asking why they are being asked to only check a box and are not asked to fill in a traditional captcha test.

Comment: I know it is new. If you reread my first comment, it is clear I did not realise the OP was referring to a checkbox.

Comment: @Joe: I know, and I am stating that I am confident that the OP is not talking about a close button.

Comment: I'm all for technology, but when it begins outsmarting me, I have to question whether the ui designers missed the human factors target. Knowing now what it was, it makes sense, but after years of the usual captch dialog, to suddenly find a blank one, no explanation, and the only widget available being the `window-close/cancel` button **at the top-right**, it did cause quite a bit of confusion. Thanks for the explanation. All following dialogs did have the captcha challenge.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: so are you saying the *I am not a robot* checkbox wasn't even there? That the google widget had not loaded?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess the stylised checkbox threw the OP, HCI in action. Where's Jakob when you need him...

Comment: The text `I am not a robot` was there, but there was absolutely no discernible `checkbox` anywhere on the dialog. I wish I would have taken a screeenshot. It was NOT a javascript blocking issue either. I allowed every one of the 5-6 remote sites it listed as needing in the NoScript dialog. Like I said, the only place I could click was the `window_close [X]` in the window decoration surrounding the dialog. The animation shown at the top of this page `white box -> green check -> ...` was not present.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: for UI issues, *always* take a screenshot. :-) I read your post as only having the big checkbox Google provides. It sounds as if the issue you had self-resolved, however.

Comment: I took a screenshot! It still doesn't show any `Captcha Box` that I can click and tell it I'm human. I'm using FireFox 33.0 on this computer which is running openSuSE 13.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: After fiddling with it extensively and reloading/refreshing and trying different levels of script and 3rd party content, I was able to get the captcha box, but only after allowing 3rd party content from `gstatic` and then after all of the hassle, it still presented a traditional captcha challenge in the bottom left of the dialog. I don't think this new `captcha-cake` is fully baked yet. If it takes dropping the security settings in my browser to work, but then reverts back to a traditional captcha -- its FUBAR and I don't need any more SNAFU's.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: *always* try to reproduce your issue without extensions enabled. Perhaps an additional domain is needed here before it all works according to plan.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I've updated the [central FAQ on browser requirements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71208) to reflect the additional 2 domains that I can see are being used.

Answer (score 4):

I just experienced the same problem after installing the [Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) extension into Chrome.  Disabling it for this domain caused the checkbox to appear again.

Try disabling adblock type extensions to see if it appears for you.