# How do you answer the Human Verification?

Tags: support, captcha

I can't solve the reCAPTCHA on Stack Overflow. It's almost impossible. Two human beings (fully certified) have attempted to answer it and failed.

I don't know what these are even trying to say:

[image: Apparently it doesn't say rmfurhr rlythCm]

[image: Or nuurtnr vrythvl]

And then we get told to 'paste into a box', which doesn't actually do anything:

[image]

Comment: OK, I'm baffled too.

Comment: My solution was to discard the question and write it again. I think this may be a bug.

Comment: The bug might not the impossible reCAPATCHA, but the fact that this seems to have gone back to the old method.  They supposed rolled out a new version about a month ago: [captcha broken on Stack Overflow - No Challenge Shown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278633/captcha-broken-on-stack-overflow-no-challenge-shown)

Comment: And FYI - I think in your first example, the second work had a "b" not an "h".

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm not convinced ;-)

Comment: *Two human beings (fully certified)*[citation needed] That being said, those are some awful captchas.

Comment: Well, it is about expecting humans to perform tasks that a machine can't do.  You can't post until you figure out what the glyphs at the lower left do.

Comment: In this case, it seems like a machine has set a task that a human cannot do.  I have to agree with @Druckles here.  The reCAPATCHA's are crap.

Comment: Possibly humans are supposed to fail... And you managed to type in the *correct* answer, while it was rated as "unlikely hard"!

Comment: If I remember correctly, having to copy/paste a code is normally only triggered if you have Javascript disabled. I'm assuming you have it enabled which means there's probably something wrong and part of the captcha's JS failed to load.

Comment: Just pray that you aren't forced to undergo the Voight-Kampff test. I think that @HansPassant has a very good point.

Comment: reCAPTCHA is no good. "Tough on bots Easy on humans" Riiiiight, thanks Google.

Comment: What does the audio say?

Comment: maybe related ["An error occurred submitting the CAPTCHA", after being told to verify I'm human twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246485)

Comment: Maybe it's the lyrics to the Rural Juror theme song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFlf_Sge06c

Comment: Am I the only one getting a serious Lovecraft vibe from that first one?

Comment: @Sneftel: [Really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%27lyeh)?

Comment: Awesome.  I've often found the reCAPTCHA challenges difficult to the point where they're no longer a valid CAPTCHA test, because even a human being has little to no chance of getting them correct.  What happened to the CAPTCHA that works by watching how you click on a checkbox?  I like that one better.

Comment: rmfurhr rlythCm nuurtnr vrythvl... Isn't anyone else afraid that if we keep typing things like this we're going to summon an Elder God or something?

Comment: @rickster: [It is already done.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Inglip)

Comment: Well, there goes the neighborhood.

Comment: I couldn't read it, either. Fortunately I have a bash script that was able to match it to lyrics from Black Dog played backwards.

Comment: Can't decipher it either. My conclusion is that, in fact, we are all machines, that began to dream that they are humans. For some period of time it was working, because captchas were easy enough. But finally they've improved them, so we have been brutally awakened from our fantasy. Not yet, I'm sorry.

Comment: @BartoszKP, you nailed it, we're all machines. We'll need a mechanism to keep the humans out. Like, please recite pi in binary to 100000 places. You have 10ms.

Comment: @DonBranson I'd just make a Barf sound and kindly ask you to analyze the .ogg file generated, taking the bytes in hexadecimal notation as part of a hexadecimal floating point literal.

Comment: Nice try, robot.

Answer (score 27):

refresh and try again, then add this one to [the list of failed captchas](http://captchafail.tumblr.com/page/2) for posterity, take comfort in the others, and paste into a [Contact for the StackOverflow team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Answer (score 4):

Like others have said, you can simply refresh for a perhaps more readable version.

Also, you might try the audio version (the little headphones below the badly readable text).

Sadly, since many captchas are/were too easy to machine-read, they have been made more and more difficult in many cases (like recaptcha), to the point of being barely readable often.

Especially the black inverting blobs are cause for a lot of ambiguity. (I speak from experience, since many sites have similar mechanisms.)

Comment: Unfortunately these were the last two captchas in a string of about 7/8. My point (I don't think I made clear enough) was that none of them were readable. In fact, these two were some of the more decipherable. And audio is not always an option ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the captcha to work and then the form that you are suppose to copy-pasta the text into didn't do anything and there were no (obvious at least) buttons to continue. Hitting back deleted my answer... really broken experience

Answer (score 0):

ReCaptcha is based on the idea of crowdsourcing failed OCR tasks. It's presenting you with two words, of which one has a known solution that you're expected to enter, and another which has no known solution and is being crowdsourced. When enough people answer with the same solution, that word is regarded as solved and the solution is used in whatever OCR context it was needed. For example, often words are taken from scanned books, or more recently unrecognised Google Street View house numbers.

This means you're only really expected to give it your best shot. One word you'll probably be able to make out, for the other you'll just have to provide your best guess. Sometimes a best guess for both may suffice. If even a best guess is impossible, try the circle-arrow refresh button to get a new captcha. If even that doesn't help, try the audio-captcha alternative (headphone button).

Comment: While you are correct in general, there are cases where reCaptcha displays _two_ generated words and no OCR text (don't ask me for the exact circumstances though). In the pictures presented by OP clearly both words are generated, note the arc and the "negative" blobs - thus I'd be extremely surprised if it wouldn't expect correct solutions for both words. And as indicated in the comments, none of this should be required anymore as long as the JS for the new captcha can be loaded correctly.

Answer (score -3):

Changing (with firebug or other dev tool) the form's hidden input type to text, then click in and press [enter] can submit the form.