# Stack Overflow CAPTCHA

Tags: discussion

How do you answer the captcha for Stack Overflow.  I'm trying to post an answer but I keep getting a captcha.  They are very hard to read, when I finally get it right, it says paste this code into the box below, I do that and nothing happens.

Comment: Seen this asked recently

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281597/how-do-you-answer-the-human-verification

Comment: Yeah - don't worry about it.  It's not just you.  Nobody can do teh CAPTCHAs.