# Unable to search due to captcha

Tags: support, captcha

Every single time I try to search for an answer, I'm unable to get past the captcha. None of the pictures will load for me so I can not select which pictures are the ones it asks for. The audio version is similar - it won't play. I had thought of reporting this error, but I can't even do that as that's not [even an option!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlIGM.png) I don't know if it has valid solutions or if they're violent or whatnot as they just don't load. Reloading more of them just gives the same result. Since I can't report it, I'm mentioning it here as I don't know where else to do so.

edit: Network blocking isn't likely as captcha loads when I use Internet Explorer on the same computer (not my default browser). I'm using an older version of Firefox that does accept third-party cookies but deletes them soon after any page that they came from is closed. Yes I know it's outdated but for various reasons it's unlikely to be updated until the end of the year.

On the other hand the inability to report the issue (because apparently only three options will ever happen) still stands.

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you use any addins that could block it? Could it be blocked at your network for some reason?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278633/captcha-broken-on-stack-overflow-no-challenge-shown?rq=1)