# NoScript blocking certain links on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, firefox

I am using Firefox 45.0 with the NoScript plugin (version 2.9.0.11) and today I noticed that I cannot use certain links in Stack Overflow anymore. When I disable NoScript, the problem disappears. For example, clicking the `Stack Exchange`, `Inbox` and `Achievements` links in the header does not open the drop down menus anymore. Also I cannot add comments anymore by clicking the `Add a comment` link.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem and knows which setting in NoScript causes this problem?

Comment: You need JS to navigate SE sites. It's been like that for a while (I can't remember where I read it on SE, though)

Comment: You're using NoScript. That's the bug.

Comment: I allowed `stackoverflow.com` and it always used to work fine. But just noticed that `sstatic.net` was blocked. And allowing it solved the problem. No idea why it was blocked. Is it new?

Comment: @rene: Okay, thank you! I guess this question was kind of useless. Should I delete it?

Comment: See *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161)*. It contains input for JavaScript whitelisting (e.g. for use in NoScript).

Answer (score 7):

The problem was, that `sstatic.net` was blocked by NoScript. Allowing that page solved my problem. Thanks to rene for pointing me to the *what else do I need* paragraph of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208):

> - The following sites should be accessible:
>
>   - [`sstatic.net` (and its subdomains) for Stack Exchange JavaScript and CSS static resources](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/)
>   - [`googleapis.com` for jQuery effects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81546/stackoverflow-com-javascript-disabled-banner/81561#81561)
>   - [`api.recaptcha.net` for viewing CAPTCHAs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57846/captcha-is-broken-or-really-hard)
>   - [`*.gstatic.com` and `apis.google.com` for viewing the Not a Robot test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278633/captcha-broken-on-stack-overflow-no-challenge-shown)
>   - [`i.stack.imgur.com` for viewing most images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64402/cannot-see-pictures-on-stack-overflow/64404#64404)
>   - [`stackauth.com` for Global Network Auto-Login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/). This feature uses HTTPS, so your browser must accept [its SSL certificate](https://stackauth.com/). It also requires a browser that supports HTML5 Local Storage, such as Internet Explorer 8+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox 3.6+ or Opera 10.61+, and you'll need to accept some third-party cookies. See also the automated tests on [Network Login Troubleshooting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help), and notes about allowing third-party cookies [in, for example, Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156828/login-problem-in-stackoverflow-in-chrome-as-third-party-cookies-appear-to-be-di/156921#156921). And beware that plugins [such as ad blockers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus) might interfere.
>   - [`gravatar.com` for viewing user avatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33774/why-do-the-gravatars-get-blocked)
>   - [`cdn.mathjax.org` to see formulas on MathJax-enabled sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133611/mathjax-is-not-defined-javascript-error-and-no-toolbar-is-shown-and-preview-do)
>   - `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` for [live updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) on your Inbox, reputation, new questions, answers and more. This also needs both your browser and your network/security to support web sockets. See [websocketstest.com](http://websocketstest.com/) to test that.

Comment: Can you edit your profile with those settings? Or is *quantserve.com* also required?

Comment: I'm blocking `quantserve.com` and didn't notice any problems with that. Also managed to edit my profile a while ago.